# VideoView can't open a video file in the Download directory (permission denied)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-videoview

I used an Android 10 AVD in the emulator. I copied a sample video file ("sample.mp4") to the emulator and then tried to play it. The activity has a `VideoView` and a `Button`. I tried to play the video when I click the button, but it failed with "permission denied". Of course, I had added the "external storage read" permission and manually enabled it in the "App info". But since it did not work, I also added `requestPermissions()` and enabled the permission at runtime. Both did not work.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/Download/sample.mp4");
        videoView.start();
    }

    val permissions = arrayOf<String>(
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    requestPermissions(permissions, 2222)
```

Error message:

```
W/VideoView: Unable to open content: /sdcard/Download/sample.mp4
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Download/sample.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
```

It's not because the path is wrong, because when I gave a fake path, the error was different.

```
Unable to open content: /sdcard/Download/samplexxx.mp4
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Download/samplexxx.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Passing `/storage/emulated/0/Download/sample.mp4` gave me the same "permission denied" error.

Comment: I think the path you are sending is incomplete filesystem path , you need to have path starting from filesystem internal/external directory storage. [Check documentation{https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()}

Comment: According to the red text in the linked page, Android 8.0+ does not allow file access using path in the shared storage.

Comment: You can't assume that the sdcard is at /sdcard, that will vary between devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to gain access

```
   if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
        }

        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
        // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

        return;
    }ode here
```